# How to use javascript to access the text after the end of <br> element

Tags: javascript

I need to read text after the `<br>` node. For example:

```
<div class= "div_class">
   <span class="span_class">Artist</span><br>Spy
```

I need to read the word `spy`. Is there any way to do it in JavaScript?

Comment: Kindly provide the html and the javascript function (if any) that you are using, from the current question details, I don't know where the <br> or other tags are which is required to formulate the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can query all the br you want to target and get the nextSibling node:

```js
// here i target all the br's in the page but you can change the selector to match your requirement
const texts = [...document.querySelectorAll('br')].map(br => br.nextSibling?.nodeValue?.trim())
console.log(texts) // ['Spy']
```

Comment: I've tried your code and it returns `['Spy\n']` (with `\n`). You can fix it by simply calling `.trim()` on `br.nextSibling?.nodeValue`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also read the html & the text using this method

```js
    document.querySelector('br').parentElement.split('<br>')[1]
```

Comment: `parentElement.split` is not a function, also, what if the parentElement has more than one `br`? And if the br is written as `<br />`?